# Laravel vuejs. In vue files data from .env file shows wrong value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

guys. I'm working on laravel 8 + Vue 3. I real server .vue files (console.log(process.env.MIX_APP_URL) - for instance) shows wrong values from .env.

I checked my .env file in server:
MIX_APP_URL=https://laravel.process.kz.
But in .vue files it gives me "http://localhost:8888/laravelprocess".

I tried php artisan config:cache, php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan key:generate etc. Please, help to find out whats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the env file you might need to restart `serve` if its still running.

It might also load additional .env files for instance:

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

Comment: did not help(( I tried, not working

Comment: Ah i misunderstood your situations, on the production server your env has the local value.
Try creating a .env.production in the project locally, when building the app it uses the .env files, not on the server in production.